# Telling wether two files are the same in C, but cannot tell the fallacy of this algorithm

Tags: c, file

My goal is to make a function telling wether two different files are the same (they contain the same content).

This is my code:

```
int are_files_equal(char* filename1, char* filename2){  
if(strcmp(filename1, filename2) == 0)
        return 1;

    struct stat stat1, stat2;

    if ( stat(filename1, &stat1) != 0 || stat(filename2, &stat2) != 0)
        return -1; // error opening files

    if(stat1.st_size != stat2.st_size)
        return 0; // files are not the same as they have a different dimension
    
    FILE *file1 = fopen(filename1, "rb");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(filename2, "rb");
    if (file1 == NULL || file2 == NULL)
    {
        return -1; // error opening files
    }
    #define BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE 512000
    unsigned char databuffer1[BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE];
    unsigned char databuffer2[BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE];
    size_t bytes;
    while ((fread(databuffer1, 1, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE, file1)) != 0)
    {
        fread(databuffer2, 1, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE, file2);
        if(memcmp(databuffer1, databuffer2, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE) != 0)
            return 0;
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return 1;
}
```

But for some reason I am not able to understand, it fails. In particular the `if(memcmp(databuffer1, databuffer2, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE) != 0)` holds true. Why does it happen? Thank you.

Comment: Collect the value returned by each `fread`. Check they are the same, and use that size to compare the arrays - the last block read is unlikely to have `BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE` bytes.

Comment: Is the size of the file a multiple of 512000? Otherwise you read garbage using `memcmp` on uninitialized areas of the array. Try with `unsigned char databuffer1[BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE] = "";`

Comment: "In particular the if(memcmp(databuffer1, databuffer2, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE) != 0) holds true." What do you mean by this? What exactly is the problem? Do you get a "the files are equal" result when the files should not be equal? Do you get a "the files are not equal" result when the files should be equal? Something else? Did you try to debug the code, in particular, to check the contents of `databuffer1` and `databuffer2` individually when the comparison is tried? Also: what do you expect to happen, if the file length is not a multiple of the buffer size? What if it's **smaller**?

Comment: ...the last block in the file will usually be smaller. You define `size_t bytes;` but didn't use it.

Comment: Aside: you don't close the files on failure.

Comment: @WeatherVane karl-knechtel thank you for your time and suggestions. It's now clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the correct buffer length. Try

```
size_t bytes;
bool matching = true;
while ((bytes = fread(databuffer1, 1, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE, file1)) != 0)
{
    if(bytes != fread(databuffer2, 1, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE, file2) ||
            memcmp(databuffer1, databuffer2, bytes) != 0) {
        matching = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(fread(databuffer2, 1, BYTES_TO_READ_AT_ONCE, file2) != 0) {
    matching = false;    // check if the whole file was read
}
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
return matching;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a side question. Is it necessary to check if the file2 has been read to its end even if we previously check that both files have the same size?

Comment: I guess not, I don't usually check they are are same size, it's easier to just try another read. `stat()` is not portable.

Comment: It is possible for the file to change between the stat call and the fopen call.